# elasticsearch parent child mergin two tables togeher

Tags: elasticsearch, mapping, parent-child

How do I do something like a JOIN in elasticsearch. I have 2 index

```
"_index": "blacklist1",
"_type": "logs",
"_id": "KS8CI-XKSID8DKSLAKS"

"_index": "raw_firewall_logs",
"_type": "logs",
"_id": "SADLFSJFOI3098WOIJFD",
```

Assuming in "raw_firewall_logs" I have a field "source_ip" that contains "123.123.123.1"

Assuming in "blacklist1" I have a field "block_ip" that contains "123.123.123.1" and a field "threat_type" containing "worm"

How should I update my mapping and how should I query so that I can see the following

```
{"source_ip": "123.123.123.1", "blacklist1": "Yes", "blacklist1": "worm"}
```

Comment: Have you tried using [Parent/Child](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/parent-child-mapping.html#parent-child-mapping) mapping?

Comment: It seems that the parent and child link you posted requires everything to be in the same index. I need it to be "many index to one index" kind of relationship